# How do I find the second to last character of a string?

Tags: java, string, string-length

I'm trying to find the second to last character of a string. I try using `word.length() -2` but I receive an error. I'm using java

```
String Word;
char c;

lc = word.length()-1;
slc = word.length()-2; // this is where I get an error.
System.out.println(lc);
System.out.println(slc);//error
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at snippet.hw5.main(hw5.java:30)

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Do you want second to last or last character?

Comment: Please tell us what language are you talking about! Show us the code, copy the exact error message. This is way too generic to be answered.

Comment: Check what I edited it to.

Comment: You're confusing `String Word` with a different variable `word` (Java variables are case-sensitive). The exception message means that you're initializing `word` somewhere else as a string with exactly one letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to count back two characters from the end of a string you first need to make sure that the string is at least two characters long, otherwise you'll be attempting to read characters at negative indices (i.e. before the start of the string):

```
if (word.length() >= 2)         // if word is at least two characters long
{
    slc = word.length() - 2;    // access the second from last character
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you could try this one:

```
public void SecondLastChar(){
    String str = "Sample String";
    int length = str.length();
    if (length >= 2)
        System.out.println("Second Last String is : " + str.charAt(length-2));
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid String");
}
```